# Error Xpath (System.ArgumentException: 'Noncompliant characters in the path.')

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, xpath

I have this error (translation from French Visual Studio error) when i try to Xpath a XML Data from a database :
**System.ArgumentException: 'Noncompliant characters in the path.'**
[Error from Visual Studio (French)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tgN.jpg)

This is my code :

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SA2426\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Proteor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password= root");
    string query = "SELECT Content From Template WHERE Id = '0108f7ac-7853-4543-8ec4-a04cb755ed46' AND Deleted = '0'";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            if(sdr.HasRows)
            {
                while(sdr.Read())
                {
                    string content = sdr["Content"].ToString();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content));

                    // Test Decode
                    string contenu = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content);

                    doc.Load(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content));

                    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                    ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
                    XmlNode FormId;                        
                    FormId = doc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::Properties/Property[attribute::Name='FormId']", ns);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FormId.OuterXml);
                }
            }                
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }            
    }
}
```

I have to decode my XML, because special chars are included in this data, as "&lt","&gt"...
i don't know how is it possible... i copy/paste the "Test Decode" in a simple xml document so as to check the xml code, and it's alright :

```html
<Root>
  <StorageObject Name="OI-GENOUILLERE ODRA-v2" Id="0108f7ac-7853-4543-8ec4-a04cb755ed46" Type="Adviser.Proteor.Library.TemplateImpl">
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="TimeCreated" Value="27/07/2017 11:14:18" /><Property Name="Enabled" Value="True" /><Property Name="TimePublished" Value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" /><Property Name="TimeLastModified" Value="10/11/2017 09:09:29" /><Property Name="Description" Value="" /><Property Name="ObjectContent" Value=""<Template>
        <Component Type="Adviser.Proteor.Library.TemplateImpl">
          <ExtendedProperty Text="OI" Key="Classification" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="35176af2-b664-42d6-a7ba-5d06602b0500" Key="ClassificationId" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="GAO" Key="Activity" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="58d942ea-8cf7-4089-879c-f8633925473b" Key="ActivityId" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="OI 36" Key="AnatomicalLevel" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="76418da5-6830-4a49-aed0-b472c11c67c6" Key="AnatomicalLevelId" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="ORTHESE INF." Key="Type" />
          <ExtendedProperty Text="13b33a27-57ce-4009-8812-00f8578982fd" Key="TypeId" />
          <Version Version.Major="0" Version.Minor="1" />
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="TimeCreated" Value="27/07/2017 11:14:18" />
            <Property Name="Enabled" Value="True" />
            <Property Name="TimePublished" Value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" />
            <Property Name="TimeLastModified" Value="10/11/2017 09:09:29" />
            <Property Name="Description" Value="" />
          </Properties>
          <Component Type="Adviser.Proteor.Library.StepImpl">
            <Properties>
              <Property Name="FormId" Value="d442dce3-fc1f-49da-92c5-b25d89d76881" />
              <Property Name="ValidationMode" Value="None" />
            </Properties>
            <Component Type="Adviser.Proteor.Library.Impl.Action.Task.OnPageLoadTrigger">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="PageNumber" Value="1" />
              </Properties>
              <Component Type="Adviser.Proteor.Library.Impl.Action.Task.SetControlValueTask">
                <Properties>
                  <Property Name="Text" Value="{agence}" />
                  <Property Name="ObjectId" Value="dc20a4e2-46d6-47fe-8c75-bf4d7ff012ba" />
                </Properties>
              </Component>
```

It's not the full code, but you can see that the code is correctly written.

Need help !!!

EDIT : There is something i've just seen at the moment. There is a xml code encapsulate in a main xml code :

the Value of the ObjectContent is not "finished" and starts with an other tag template

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) for `XmlDocument.Load`, this overload:

> Loads the XML document from the specified URL.

What you're passing it isn't an URL, it's a `string` that contains the XML content. This is why the error message states that you have invalid characters in your path - your XML isn't a path at all.

You want to use the [`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the XmlDocument method, but i have a new error : '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Do you know what does that mean ? "<" is a started tag, so how can i have this error ?

Comment: It means you have `<` inside an attribute, e.g `<element attr="<" />`, which is illegal. It should be `<element attr="&lt;" />`. You need to provide a [mcve], but if I had to guess then you need to remove the `HtmlDecode`.